# Does SonarLint work on RDz for Cobol code?

Tags: sonarqube, cobol, sonarlint

Let's assume that I have a SonarQube instance that is configured with the Cobol plugin and that created my own Cobol quality profile.

Now, my Cobol developers are using IBM RDz, which is an Eclipse based IDE.

Would SonarLint allow me to do the integration between RDz and SonarQube for Cobol code.
In other words, will my Cobol code be checked against my rules (defined in SonarQube) as I am programming on RDz.

Comment: What happened when you tried? You may find a better place to ask (more specific expertise available) at the IBM Rational Cafe, https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/category?id=33333333-0000-0000-0000-000000000281

Comment: Hi Bill, we currently don't have RDz so I can't give it a try.  Using RDz involves performing some changes on the mainframe side so it may (will) take a while.  I already have SonarQube integrated with Visual Studio and Eclipse (via SonarLint) and I am hopping to do the same with IBM RDz.  If no one tried, I will do it (eventually) and reply to that thread to say if it works or not.  Also, thanks for the link.  I will have a look to see if I can find something on that side.

Answer (score 3):

As of today (SonarLint 2.6) it doesn't work.

SonarLint for Eclipse was designed to work in most standard Eclipse based IDEs as long as they are using "standard" editors and standard resources.

However we also have some constraints/requirements:

- SonarLint analyzers are designed to work with physical files (ie available on local hard drive). For Cobol it is common to have the IDE displaying a remote view of the content on the mainframe. We partially solved that on SonarLint side by creating a local copy of the file prior to start the analysis, and we are also progressively upgrading our analyzers to support an intermediate virtual filesystem layer.
- The SonarSource Cobol analyzer [need some configuration](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/COBOL+Plugin+Advanced+Configuration) to work properly. You may have to manually configure those properties to make the analysis work. For copybooks that may again be complex if you don't have a local copy of them.

IBM RDz/IDz actually use standard editors, and so we confirmed that SonarLint issues are properly displayed. But there is a problem with the way RDz (re)define the resource hierarchy. SonarLint heavily relies on Eclipse IProject/IFile but RDz has its own abstraction, at least for remote projects.

So in the current state, it is not possible to use SonarLint on RDz.

Answer (score 0):

It's available.
Cf. https://developer.ibm.com/mainframe/2017/07/07/sonarlint-integration-developer-z-systems/.
But we are evaluating it and we face some bugs and some performance matters (march 2018). The IBM Labs are working on fixing it.